# Creating a new file using a variable in python

Tags: python, file, variables, makefile

The code that I am currently using is this:

```
date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
filename = ('attendence{}' + str(date) +'.txt')
f = open(filename, 'w+')
```

However, the error I receive is this:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'attendence{}31/03/17.txt'
```

The error is not with other parts of my code as this will work.

```
f = open('attendence{}.txt', 'w+')
```

my end goal is to create a new file that contains the current date.

Comment: What do you *want* the name of the file to be?

Comment: I'm not sure what operating system you're on, but you generally can't use slashes in filenames; they'll be interpreted as directory separators.

Comment: attendance{}''datehere''.txt

Comment: You should use context management. `with open(filename, 'w+') as f: ...`

Comment: I would suggest removing the slashes, so `date = time.strftime("%d%m%y")` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the date format :

```
date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
```

You could try :

```
date = time.strftime("%d_%m_%y")
```

`'attendence{}31/03/17.txt'` isn't just a filename, it's a relative path with :

- 1 folder : `'attendence{}31'`
- 1 subfolder : `'03'`
- 1 filename `'17.txt'`.

Python is complaining that the folder `'attendence{}31/03'` doesn't exist.

Note that `{}` might confuse the system, some programs or some users. If there's no information inside the curly brackets, you might as well remove them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer  have changed the date to have . instead of / and it now works!